# Variable voltage switching 12vdc

Tags: voltage, switches, relay, variable

I am looking for a circuit that would be switching a relay coil and few small leds (max 3A) with a low voltage input. Now the input is variable voltage 1.1v to 5v produced by a hall sensor pot. I want the circuit to be switched on when my input reaches 1.2 or 1.3v to switch a relay with 12vdc. Also the 1.1v to 5v values can not be affected by this additional circuit. Any help greatly appreciated .

Comment: Use a comparator.

Comment: Any suggestion on it , diagram ? Im coming from auto elec. field and not too familiar with IC chips. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestion on it , diagram ? Im coming from auto elec. field and
>   not too familiar with IC chips. thanks

There are plenty of examples on the web. Here is one: -

[image]

You'll need a 1.25 volt reference to feed one input of the LM339 and the other input is from your hall sensor. The voltage reference is common-place and there are many options such as [this link](https://www.mouser.co.uk/Power/Power-Management-ICs/Voltage-References/_/N-6g7lz?P=1z0w6z0) from Mouser.

Q1 is virtually any PNP transistor. The 470 ohm and LED are optional.

Comment: So using a stepdown dc/dc as ref v to comparator , input from hall sensor to comparator and a P=channel Mosfet to drive the coil of a relay with a flywheel diode ?

Comment: That would work but make sure you filter the stepped-down voltage to remove ripple. You might also consider adding a bit of hysteresis when Vin is very close to Vref - this would prevent relay chattering.

Comment: Im still not sure where I will be feeding the stepdown from as the 12vdc is also variable ie. vehicle 12vdc that ranges anywhere from 9 to 14. I also have the steady 5v that supplies the hall sensor but i would prefer having that circuit as little interrupted as possible.

Comment: That is why I recommended a 1.25 volt voltage reference and gave you links to Mouser. Having said that I doubt very much that using a high impedance potential divider from 5 volts is going to upset anything.

Comment: 1.25 would be acceptable but having an adjustable v ref would be much preferred for my application ie. 1.1 to 1.6. but having main components figured out I can play about with the variables a bit and see what suites me best. also could you just throw me the part number of mouser part , I dont seem to be able to access the link. thank you.

Comment: The mouser link works at my end and takes you to a list of about 100 devices. Some will be good for you (package size, technology) and others won't - that's your decision. Use a 100 k potentiometer from the 5 volt rail to feed the +input is a good option. You can even put a 200 kohm fixed resistor between top of pot and 5 volts to restrict wiper voltages to no more than 1.667 volts too.

Comment: found this : Texas Instruments LMR12010XMKE/NOPB which I think will be suited for my application. now just to find a diagram for it, but If anyone has one handy , would be much appreciated

Comment: That's a switching regulator - you want a 1.25 volt voltage reference. There are plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Use a comparator to sense whether the signal is above or below your 1.25 V threshold.  Use the output of the comparator to turn on a transistor, which then turns on a relay.

Driving a relay from a digital signal has been discussed many times here before, so I won't repeat it.  [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/296376/4512) is one example.